# Using camera animation as base for motion tracking solve

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a camera animation (FBX or alembic) as the starting point for the motion tracking solve in Blender?

I'm using a method of tracking a camera live but the data it generates is not quite accurate enough for a "final track".

Ideally I'd like to input this animation as a base and have blender refine off of it to get a better solve.  Is this even possible though?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds logistically impossible. If the track and animation are partially inaccurate, how can blender know which one is right? The best you can have is interpolating between points where they agree, which may be arbitrary and unreliable.

In the case that the animation is meant to constrain the motion track somehow (IE: the camera will ONLY move to the right at this time, regardless of how much: ignore all apparent leftward movements), you have significantly more hope, but it may only be implementable by scripting. In that case, I’d iterate over the keyframes and make an array of transformations, then run all the transformations at once (to avoid re-transforming future keyframes over and over as we move forward in time).